# PyInstaller FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] when using Pyromat

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When creating an exe file with --onefile pyinstaller while using pyromat the process seems to run without errors, but when running the exe the following error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_start.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "pyromat\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "pyromat\reg.py", line 249, in regload
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the following path: 'C:\\Users\\"username"~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI45442\\pyromat\\registry'
[22672] Failed to execute script 'gui_start' due to unhandled exception!
```

while without:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_start.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "pyromat\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "pyromat\reg.py", line 249, in regload
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the following path: 'C:\\Users\\"username"\\PycharmProjects\\gasLeakToExe\\dist\\gui_start\\_internal\\pyromat\\registry'
[24500] Failed to execute script 'gui_start' due to unhandled exception!
```

is there a way of resolving this issue?

To deal with this, I tried writing a hook file:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

hiddeninstall = ["utility","units","reg","dat","config","data.if97",
                 "data.ig","data.ig2","data.igmix","data.mp1"]
datas = collect_data_files("data.ig")
datas +=  collect_data_files("data.ig2")
datas += collect_data_files("data.igmix")
datas += collect_data_files("data.mp")
```

but it didn't work then either.
it almost seems like I would need to rewrite part of the pyromat module and/or copy the files into my project.